# Is the pH of a solution (orange juice) affected by the presence of a metal?

Tags: acid-base, ph, metal

Is the pH of a solution (orange juice) affected by the presence of a metal (aluminium, tin or iron for example)? I know that the metal will corrode in the presence of an acid (citric acid in this case), but will the metal have any effect on the actual acidity of the solution?

Comment: Is there some reason / context behind this question? Anyway, if the acid does react with the metal, then the amount of $\ce{H+}$ ions will decrease and pH will increase, leading to a less acidic solution (as you would expect, since the acid is reacted away).